# Connectedness proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ $\subset$ $($ $V$, $|$$|$.$|$$|$$)$. If for every pair of points $x$, $y$ $\in$ $A$, there exists a continuous function $f$ $:$ $[$$0$, $1$$]$ $\to$ $A$ with $f$$($$0$$)$ = $x$ and $f$$($$1$$)$ = $y$, then $A$ is connected.

Intuitively, I think this statement is true. But I have a hard time to prove a set is connected. Do I also need to prove by contradiction?

Answer (score 4):

This notion is known as path-connectedness. Contradiction is the way to go here, like you thought.

Here's an idea to start you off. Let $A = U \cup V$ be disconnected, and pick a continuous function $f: [0,1] \to A$ connecting a point $x \in U$ to a point $y \in V$ (that is, $f(0) = x$ and $f(1)=y$). Do you have an idea on how to continue from here?